# ReactJS, new axios call at every render of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically render some components mapping an array of objects from an API call. I can't wrap my head around the syntax of this one.

I have to fetch from this url:

```
https://fakestoreapi.com/products
```

And for each object in the array I have to render Product.js inside ProductContainer.js.

ProductContainer.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles/ProductContainer.scss";
import Product from "./Product";

const ProductContainer = () => {
  const [productArray, setProductArray] = useState("");
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");
  const [nameUrl, setNameUrl] = useState("");
  const [priceUrl, setPriceUrl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products").then((res) => {
      setProductArray(res.data);
      setImgUrl(res.data.image);
      setNameUrl(res.data.title);
      setPriceUrl(res.data.price);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="product-container">
      {productArray.map((e) => {
        <Product imgUrl={imgUrl} nameUrl={nameUrl} priceUrl={priceUrl} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductContainer;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact issue? 
It works exactly how it is supposed to work:  you pass [] for useEffect, which means, that axios.get ... will trigger only after first rerender, and if your component rerenders, useEffect triggers, as it should.

Comment: Right now the issue is that I get "productArray.map is not a function", but I really can't figure out why.

Comment: The response you just fetched, have you converted it into json first..??

Comment: I tried both ways, but unfortunately I still get "productArray.map is not a function"

Comment: @p4avinash this is axios, axios returns data object. 
 just console.log res, before setting res.data, because maybe there is a nested object inside, instead of array. Debug properly. Also, don't set all the state to string, productArray is an array, so it is better to set [] or null.

Answer (score 0):

The `image`, `title` and `price` are properties of each product, not of the whole response from the API.

Also `productArray` should be initialized to an array and not a string.

So

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../styles/ProductContainer.scss";
import Product from "./Product";

const ProductContainer = () => {
  const [productArray, setProductArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products").then((res) => {
      setProductArray(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="product-container">
      {productArray.map((product) => {
        <Product imgUrl={product.image} name={product.name} price={product.price} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductContainer;
```